# how to create duplicate report on a same server

Tags: ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005, reporting-services

My manager asked me to update the .rdl file from prod to dev. But before doing that I have to keep that old report as it is and have to create a duplicate report on same server and that too be I am working on browser.

I have downloaded the the .rdl file and renamed the report as ***_old also. But I am not able to understand how to create another same report with same datasources and everything.

I can see an option update next to edit button. I am assuming that if I get a duplicate report on the same server I can update the .rdl file with that update button.

Please help me with this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
- Download the report RDL file from the report manager.
- Rename the rdl file eg. MyReport1_old.rdl
- Upload the report rdl file from the report manager.
```

Now you will have the original report (MyReport1) and the copy of it(MyReport1_old).